# Electron renders CSS differently than Chrome

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, electron, primeng

I want to apply an outline to elements, when focused by pressing tab. I am facing the issue, that when i run my app with electron, that the outline is not circular shape as expected, but it is a box.

I investigated which css rules are applied in each scenario, but didnt find any difference.

Anyone faced that issue before?

Electron:

[image: Electron]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was added in Chromium 94.

Electron is running on an older version of Chrome that didn't support rounded outlines (-> aka outlines follow border-radius) yet. Try utilizing a box-shadow without blur instead.

Comment: thank you for that quick respond. tried box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5rem black but still box shaped, not circular :(

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? Would help suggest the correct changes in that case.

Comment: ```this.renderer.setStyle((element, 'box-shadow', '0 0 0 0.5rem var(--colorD)');```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help. I need something reproduceable, preferably using a stack snippet. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: so your solution worked, instead of outline using box-shadow. the problem in my case was, that the box-shadow was overwritten/removed by some of my global css. so i tried to force it, by adding `!important` to my css, but their seems to be a bug, the `Renderer2.setStyle` method is not supporting `!important`. when i use `Renderer2.setAttribute(element, 'style', 'box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5rem var(--colorD) !important')` it is working, thanks for your help, buddy

Comment: Glad it's working for you :)